# Where can I find Ubuntu One client for Mac?

Tags: ubuntu-one, macosx

I have a lot of stuff on **Ubuntu One** and I want to download it before the services close down. Unfortunately I cannot find the Ubuntu One client for Mac. There is nothing on the official site as [Ubuntu One for Mac](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/mac/)

Did they remove it when they announced the shut down of Ubuntu One? Where can I get it downloaded?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your query, but as per the [help docs](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-about-my-files/): "_… [the Ubuntu One team] are also planning to add the ability to download all your content in a .zip file._" If you need to download all your files, that will be a good alternative to the platform specific clients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the official site **Ubuntu One** will be discontinued effective from June 1st, 2014. You may need to back-up your files which are already lying under the cloud as soon as possible.

Nevertherless, if you've gone through the **Ubuntu One help [FAQ's](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/)** properly, you can see **[Where do I get Ubuntu One for Mac?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/where-do-i-get-ubuntu-one-for-mac/)**  under ***U1 for Mac*** which gives you the client to be downloaded.

In case, if you're a premium user I'd strongly recommend you to go through their FAQ's to get a proper understanding on certain scenarios that you're stuck with.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to get it on an alternate site, e.g. [here](http://www.heise.de/download/ubuntu-one-1187816.html) to get your files.

Maybe you also want [to contact the Ubuntu One Team](https://one.ubuntu.com/contact/) to get support for your request.

Comment: The installer has been removed there too. I will contact the Ubuntu One team.

Comment: @Apfelsaft found one here: http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/27471-ubuntu_one